# Could build module 'AFNetworking' in cocoapods

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I use the Cocoapods modular project to import private pod, 
the **O2OIntegrationModules** pod can not successfully import **AFNetworking** in the Pod Project in Workspace, causing the main project to compile failed, but SDWebImage and other libraries can be successful.

- Pod version   : 1.2.0
- Xcode version : 8.2.1
- MacOS version : 10.12

## Modular

- **O2OIntegrationModules** dependency **O2OIntegrationHelps**
- **O2OIntegrationHelps** dependency **O2OKit**
- **O2OKit** dependcy **AFNetworking** **SDWebImage** **MJRefresh**

I tried to delete all files inside the ModuleCache folder and pod deintegrate, pod clean, pod reinstall, restart Xcode, restart Mac, but has 
always failed to compile.

this my error message:

[image]

Anyone ever encountered this problem?  help me, please.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved, because the **podspec** configuration out of the problem, not configured s.homepage s.xxx.target s.platform

```
s.platform     = :ios, "8.0"
s.ios.deployment_target = "8.0"
```

Stupid!!!

Comment: I forgot the deployment_target config, after add it, problem gone, thanks